# New way of directx coding

Tags: directx

I have some directx knowledge and i want to continue learning it. But i found that microsot have changed the way of coding in it and removed d3dx libraries from it from win 8 and puted directx sdk in win8sdk and jun2010 version of directxsdk doesnt work in it. What is best way to continue learning it? Because new way of coding still hasnt good refrences and sample codes.  There is a new framework that microsot gave for directx for vs2013 but im very unfamilliar with it and dont know what this is. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any *"new way of coding"*. DirectX API itself remain unchanged. They only deprecated some helper libraries, but still you can find alternatives.

Even if you continue to learn with DirectX SDK you loose nothing.

I'm also not aware of any *"new framework that microsoft gave for directx for vs2013"*, but since VS2012 they've added Express versions of Studio "for Windows" and "for Windows Desktop". This naming is a little misleading. Probably, you've downloaded "for Windows" version, where there is no good old native C++ desktop project templates available, but only templates for Windows Store Apps. So, try "Desktop" one.

For more details and helpful links about DirectX SDK vs Windows SDK, see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362041/directx-sdk-vs-windows-sdk-which-one-to-use/20367764#20367764).

Comment: im trying to find a link about that framework but for simple question : if I want to continue old version of directx after that how can I don't use d3dx function and remove them from my code? with result of last code?

Comment: ok. there is no need to answer this I found my  answer in link you gave in other posts. but as new framework: I mean if you open vs2012 with a plugin installed you find there is a new project for directx and there is no need to make an empty win32 project for directx but its code is no similar to any previous directxproject ive seen and if you run it there is a box with texture that is turning. I don't know what that really is. and new developers now are working with that or .....?

Comment: and one more new question: how much you know about mantle? is this going to be a replacement for directx and opengl? thanks

Comment: `if you open vs2012 with a plugin installed` which plugin do you mean? Probably what you've seen is a [Windows Store Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/) (Windows 8 "Metro style"), and they are pretty different from classic windowed Desktop apps.

Comment: About Mantle I know really nothing, but that it is a some kind of low level API that will trade-off device compatibility for performance. We already have nVidia analog called nvAPI.

Answer (score 1):

VS 2012 and VS 2013 include Direct3D templates for Windows Store apps and Windows phone. These set up a new 'framework' using WinRT APIs and the ICoreWindows swap chain that supports Windows 8.x or Windows Phone 8. You use Direct3D 11 or Direct2D for rendering basically the same way you did with Win32 desktop applications, but using a different input, main game loop, windows message, and Present model.

There are no built-in Direct3D templates for Win32 desktop applications installed with VS 2012 or VS 2013. Instead you'd use a classic Win32 windowed application template and then add Direct3D to it. You can use the [Win32 desktop tutorials](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef) as a guide for doing this.

**UPDATE** Alternatively, you can use this extension: [Direct3D Win32 Game Visual Studio template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx).

For more information on the overlap between Windows Store apps and Win32 desktop app programming, see [Dual-use Coding Techniques for Games](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/09/17/dual-use-coding-techniques-for-games.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You Can always download the older [DirectX SDK](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/SDK-DDK/DirectX-Software-Development-Kit.shtml) and install it in visual studio (even if it is VS2012 or VS2013) so you can follow along with any book or tutorial, because most of them, if not all, are tailored for the older DirectX (the one with d3dx).

Comment: I don't think Microsoft officially supports DirectX SDK.

Comment: what you mean doesnt support directx officially? you mean now just winsdk is supported?

Comment: Yes, you can't download DirectX SDK ( june 2010 for example) from Microsoft's website, as far as I know. However the windows SDK is available with Visual Studio (2012 or 2013 any edition) including the core DirectX libraries.

Comment: See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) article.